# Convert AWS URL to something shorter (without database)

Tags: url-rewriting, amazon-web-services, hex, ascii

We're serving up a bunch of images on our website that are actually hosted on AWS, and they're all named like 0E261DDA-CBB7-4B99-B863-6D7640DC2FD8.jpg.  To keep it simple the path to these images via our website is basically keeping the same name for the image - we just strip out the dashes to make it a little bit shorter.

But since we'll be sharing the path to these images via twitter we'd love for the string to be even shorter still, but we don't want to use a database for URL shortening (either rolling our own or using someone else's).  Would rather just have a lossless compression scheme on the string.

Given the fact that the AWS name is apparently only using hexadecimal characters, it would seem that converting it to ascii (after removing the dashes) would at least get us a bit of compression and it would be easy to do the lookup back to the actual path on the server.

Anybody have/seen a little bit of code that can spit out a URL-safe ascii equivalent to the aforementioned hex string?

Comment: Are you intending to serve the images directly from s3/cloudfront? or do you want to pass the urls through your server/instance?

Comment: Passing through our server.  So the user currently sees http://ourcompanyurl.com/?p=0E261DDA-CBB7-4B99-B863-6D7640DC2FD8 and ideally they'd see http://ourcompanyurl.com/?p=somethingshorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a higher base. Hexidecimal is base 16. You could use a number of a higher base (36 is common in url shortners, but you could go up to 62 (10 digits, 26 upper case letters 26 lower case letters)

Your base 16 string:

```
0E261DDACBB74B99B8636D7640DC2FD8
```

In base 36:

```
U5LC6FOS2F9E70WW3KAT3KK8
```

In base 62 (bit less reliable, case sensitive):

```
QhJL1gbuZhsyJOIQ3ia0u
```

Comment: Yup, totally makes sense - thanks!  Though why is base62 'less reliable'?

Comment: Its case sensitive, where as base 36 could be converted to uppercase and it will still convert properly. I wouldn't expect this to be a huge issue as a long as you aware of it.

Comment: @Oscar It should be pretty easy to write no matter what platform you are using.

Comment: And yet every example that comes up in pages and pages of results is written in C#... because the language has built-in functions to do it for you.  I've yet to see one in C.

Comment: @Oscar The core of the concept can should only be a handful of lines (just base conversion and string manipulation). But different platforms have varying about of boilerplate needed to handle http requests.

Comment: Not too worried about the HTTP; it's more an issue of 30+ hex digits (as in a UUID) exceeding the math range of any platform I'll be using.  Thus converting to base 36 is a problem.